# jQuery: bind event in ajax callback doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, bind, mapbox

I use Mapbox to display markers on a map. The file `json.php` fetches the data from the database and outputs a json object. I decided to seperate that file because I need the raw data also for other operations. On the first beta site, the JSON object was just stored into a variable in `map_data.js`, where the data is evaluated. Now the data is fetched via AJAX, but now the click event doesn't work anymore. When the mouse hovers a marker, a tooltip is displayed (works!), when the user clicks on a marker, detailed Information should be displayed. What is the issue?

```
 (function($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.get('json.php', function(data) {
           build_map(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
        });
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'xxxxxxxxxx', {
                        zoomControl: false
                    }).setView([51.2016, 6.6857], 9);

        function build_map(data)
            {
                var geoJson = data;

                // Set a custom icon on each marker based on feature properties
                map.markerLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
                  var marker = e.layer,
                  feature = marker.feature;
                  marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
                });

                // Add features to the map
                map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);

                // Tooltip on mouseover
                map.markerLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                  e.layer.openPopup();
                });
                map.markerLayer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
                  e.layer.closePopup();
                });

                // Listen for individual marker clicks
                map.markerLayer.on('click',function(e) {
                  // Force the popup closed.
                  e.layer.closePopup();
                  var feature = e.layer.feature;
                  var member = '(The DIV)';
                  document.getElementById('member').innerHTML = member;
                });
            }

 });
 })(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Is it because the onlcick triggers:  e.layer.closePopup();

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question maybe, could you create a fiddle?

Comment: Yes the popup (the tooltip) is supposed to close, but the detailed information (member)  does not open.

Comment: This: `document.getElementById('member').innerHTML = member;` doesn't work. Perhaps the two lines before do not work either. The popup closing works!

Comment: I also tried `$("member").html( member );`, but this doesn't work either. The variable `member` is correct, I can see it via `alert(member);`

Comment: Is it: var feature = e.layer.feature ??? This could this be creating some sort of conflict since the var being defined is is being used in itself?

Comment: You could try and replace the doc.getelementById with: 

$(document).on("click", "#member", function (e) {
$(this).innerHTML(member);});

Comment: I tried, but `map.markerLayer` has to be clicked so that the member div is filled with information.

Comment: The problem is in your `onclick` callback. It's not quite clear from your code what you're trying to accomplish there. Right now, when the `map.markLayer` is clicked, `'(The DIV)'` should appear in an element with id `member`. Creating a fiddle with a simplified example reproducing the problem would probably clarify matters.

Comment: Yes, and this worked. But as I had to wrap the whole stuff into the function `build_map`, `'(The DIV)'` does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to add `$("#thedivid").css('display', 'block');` to the function.

It was just a CSS issue.